# Binding Custom HScroll to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, horizontal-scrolling

### I'm having problem with binding Hscroll to datagridview. I need to have bigger scoll, than default DGV one. So i need to bind custom scroll to dgv or increase height of default one. I'm using WinForms.

I have tried the following code, but it doesnt fit my needs, the scroll stopped in middle of my dgv, manipulating values had no effect on it.

```
private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    int totalwidth = dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        totalwidth += dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width  ;
    }

    hScrollBar1.LargeChange = dataGridView1.Width;
    hScrollBar1.SmallChange = dataGridView1.Columns[gsKodTowaruDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index].Width;

    if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
    {
        hScrollBar1.Value = e.NewValue;          
    }
}

private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)           
{
    dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset = e.NewValue;
}
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: how do you set the maximum value? maybe `totalwidth` ??

Comment: yes, it doesnt work propperly this way

Comment: What do you mean by a) 'not properly' and b) by 'yes'. If you don't set the maximum correctly the scrollbar obviously cannot work. You also need to adapt it whenever columns get added or resized. Show the code!

Comment: a) - not moving all the way, goes to about 50% of the "default" scrollbar lenght. ----



   hScrollBar1.Maximum = totalwidth;
            hScrollBar1.LargeChange = dataGridView1.Width+50;
            hScrollBar1.SmallChange = dataGridView1.Columns[gsKodTowaruDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index].Width;

after for loop it looks like that right now ^^

Comment: One simple solution is to synch with the dgv's hscrollbar: `hScrollBar1.Maximum = totalwidth;
HScrollBar vBar = dataGridView1.Controls.OfType<HScrollBar>().First();
hScrollBar1.LargeChange = vBar != null ? vBar.LargeChange : totalwidth / 4;
`

Comment: Honestly, that didn't do the trick.
But i figured out the problem. 
DGV method was not hit. Problem seems to be solved by moving stuff from DGV scroll method to onload method

Answer (score -1):

You have to bind these values to react to change right?
You are using a maxWidth value without using it.

Also, you should react to Resize Event on the DataGridView to make sure the HScroll values do change.

Comment: My bad, by the accident i deleted hScrollbar1.Maximum = totalwidth.
But it doesnt work this way. 
Uhm, it works, but maximum seems  to be somewhere in the middle of DGV..